# CPU not calling IRQ0?

Tags: clock, interrupt-handling, irq

I am writting an OS and trying to use the PIT. I have a handler written and wrote an ISR entry for the IRQ0 (Interrupt 32). The handler is not being called at all. I am pretty sure I am not putting the ISR entry in right. Any suggestions? Here is my ASM code

```
mov dword EAX, irq_common_stub
        mov byte [_NATIVE_IDT_Contents + 0x100], AL
        mov byte [_NATIVE_IDT_Contents + 0x101], AH
        mov byte [_NATIVE_IDT_Contents + 0x102], 0x8
        mov byte [_NATIVE_IDT_Contents + 0x105], 0x8E
        shr dword EAX, 0x10
        mov byte [_NATIVE_IDT_Contents + 0x106], AL
        mov byte [_NATIVE_IDT_Contents + 0x107], AH
```

My code to init the PIT is

```
     public static void PIT_Init(uint frequency)
    {
        uint divisor = 1193180 / frequency;
        GruntyOS.IO.Ports.Outb(0x43, 0x36);
        byte l = (byte)(divisor & 0xFF);
        byte h = (byte)((divisor >> 8) & 0xFF);
        GruntyOS.IO.Ports.Outb(0x40, l);
        GruntyOS.IO.Ports.Outb(0x40, h);
    }
```

The handler is

```
public static void HandlePIT()
    {
        GruntyOS.IO.Ports.Outb(0xA0, 0x20);
        GruntyOS.IO.Ports.Outb(0x20, 0x20);

        print("Tick: " + Tick.ToString());
        Tick++;
    }
```

Which is called from

```
irq_common_stub:
pusha                  

mov ax, ds              
push eax                 

mov ax, 0x10 
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

call System_Void__GruntyOS_Entry_HandlePIT__

pop ebx       
mov ds, bx
mov es, bx
mov fs, bx
mov gs, bx

popa                  
add esp, 8     
sti
iret
```

Comment: This can't be answered. We can't just guess how you are trying to achieve this. Please provide more details if you want help.

Comment: I am simply writing to the IDT and then I have my code to initialize it. My code is in C# (There is a project called Cosmos which lets you write native C# code that gets converted to x86) I included the code in the question. That gets called after the ISR has been assigned.

Comment: Now at least we know you are targeting x86... Don't you think this kind of info may be useful?

Comment: I do , I just wasn't thinking and I really do not know that many platforms besides ARM that are not x86.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help. Its a simple kernel 
that is capable of handling IRQs and Exceptions.

http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/irqs.htm

http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2874/en